# make enter button of textbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

i have textbox multi way to fill it 
  i can fill it from keyboard normally and the other way by clicking button i created on forum something like calculator

when i click button 1 the textbox  fill by number 1 and so 
and i have button name and work should be like enter key

i have event keydown to send the value i fill it on the text box and work fine
but i need the button that called enter work as the event keydown of the textbox

in short word i need to use touchscreen to enter number to textbox and button to send the value of the textbox to my work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to call the same code from two different places you should put it in a separate method, then call that method at will.

Comment: thank you
that what i am trying to do 
,what i have to do in enter event to work as enter key press but the press is on a button

Comment: Like I said, [**use a separate method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831f9wka.aspx).

Comment: ok ok ok in method one i used key_down method and the second method i want to use is a button , in key_down method there is something like " If (e.Key = Key.Enter) Then  " but in button method what the value to use the button.Click as key.enter

Comment: No, you're supposed to write a custom method! Write one on your own, for example: `Private Sub DoStuff()`, put your code in there and call it both from the button and the KeyDown event.

Comment: I'll write an answer for you, but I'd recommend you get a book about programming if you're planning to really get into it. These kinds of things that I'm talking about are very important to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the same code at two different occasions you should put your code in a [**separate method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/831f9wka.aspx) and then call that at will.

By dividing your code like this you improve both readability and debuggability, and you make your code easier to understand and update.

Here's a brief example:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
        UpdateStatus("Enter was pressed.") 'Call custom method.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    UpdateStatus("Button1 was pressed. Hello World!") 'Call custom method.
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateStatus(ByVal Text As String) 'Custom method declaration.
    TextBox1.Text = Text
    'In here is where you'd put your code.
End Sub
```